# Postgres Internals

Tags: database, postgresql, io, disk-io

I want to learn how postgres writes it data into the file (FileFormat & Structure ). What is the encoding method and compression method used to store these data. Is compression is Cell Level or Entire table level.How data modification occurs in files. How postgres optimized it IO handling? can anyone send links or documents realted to these topics.

Comment: Visit https://www.postgresql.org/ (who would have thought...). There you can study the documentation and even the source code.

Comment: @sticky bit yes  i gone through the  docs. but i could't find the compression & IO related handling

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the below links
[https://momjian.us/main/presentations/internals.html][1]
[http://www.interdb.jp/pg/][2]
[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/internals.html][3]
But I agree with [@stickybit][4], please search the web it will save the editors time & you will also get a wealth of knowledge.


  [1]: https://momjian.us/main/presentations/internals.html
  [2]: http://www.interdb.jp/pg/
  [3]: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/internals.html
  [4]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit
```